# SQL Server command line tool version compatibility with different versions of SQL Servers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012, sqlcmd

I have different versions of SQL Server to whom I need to connect from an EC2 which is based on CentOS. I have sqlcmd downloaded as below:

```
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Command Line Tool
Version 13.0.0001.0 Linux
Copyright (c) 2012 Microsoft.
```

This works for some SQL Servers but not for the other versions that I have like SQL Server 2005. Is there any way if I can achieve this? I am having hard time uninstalling and installing the `sqlcmd` utility. Please guide.

Comment: `sqlcmd` supports all **supported** versions of SQL Server. 2005 has been long out of support, and 2008 is unsupported as well. As installing and uninstalling, have you read the documentation? [Install sqlcmd and bcp the SQL Server command-line tools on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: What do I do if I need to connect to multiple SQL Servers in one? :(

Comment: Considering you're using CentOS (which is not a supported OS for `sqlcmd`) you might be better off using [`mssql-cli`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/mssql-cli?view=sql-server-ver15) which does support CentOS, *however* I doubt it supports unsupported versions of SQL Server still.

Comment: *"What do I do if I need to connect to multiple SQL Servers in one"* you have to use unsupported tools for unsupported versions of SQL Server; none of which are available on Linux.